# Updating the manual test plan from the automation

Tags: build, continuous-integration, automated-tests, azure-devops, mstest

Good afternoon,

I wonder if it is possible to perform the process below. I've tried it in many ways, but I still can not get any positive results. So I do not know if it's possible to do this or I really can not.

I've created a test automation project to run on build, with BDD.
I created the project and checked in on VSTS.
After that, I created the build and ran my test solution.
All the tests were run correctly and in the build result shows me how many tests passed and how many failed.

However, these my tests were built based on the test plan that already existed previously. So they are all related to an existing test case in VSTS.
I made the automation link with the test case, but when I run the test on the build it does nothing with this link information.

I wonder if it is possible, when I run the build with the tests, can you make the test plan update with the result of the Build execution?

For example:

Test case ID: 1 is automated and if I check it there is the automation link with it. When I run automation and the test passes, test case 1 will be updated to passed.
When I access the test plan, it will be possible to see that the test has passed, and it is not necessary to verify the result of the build. It will already be up to date.

Is it possible or really I can not?

Remembering that my automation is being run by the vsTest task of the build.

Comment: Are you running the tests by specifying a test plan, or are you specifying a test assembly?

Comment: From what I've seen, my project generates a .dll with the tests. So when I did, I referenced an assembly.
When I tried to put it as a plan, it made a mistake in the buil and did not run the tests.
But when I created the tests, I made the association of it right, if I edit the test case it presents the automation and its design associated with the case.

Comment: The VsTest task can run tests either my test assembly **or** by test plan. Try running the tests by test plan.

Comment: @DanielMann It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VsTest task can run tests either my test assembly or by test plan. If you're running by test assembly, it's not going to do anything involving your test plan.

Run the tests by test plan and you should get the behavior you're expecting.